# Define Blend Expression ViewModel definition for RelativeSource binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls, blend

I have an `UserControl` (MyCompositeView) where I add some other `UserControls` (MyDetailView). To get intellisense and refactoring ability I add to the CompositeView the `d:DataContext` in `xaml`.

To Manipulate the UserControl while adding them an new DataContext I bind the Visiblity to the RelativeSource (my CompositeViewModel). Unfortunately the matching against the `MyCompositeViewModel` isn't working for this Binding in the Editor.

Is there a way to let visual studio know that my `DataContext` of `DataContext.DetailsIsVisible` is from the type `MyCompositeViewModel`?

```
<UserControl 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    x:Class="Example.MyCompositeView"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=MyCompositeViewModel}"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="300"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

     <Grid>
        <detail:MyDetailView 
            DataContext="{Binding Path=DetailViewModel}"
            Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
                Path=DataContext.DetailsIsVisible,
                Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilty}}" />
     </Grid>

 </UserControl>
```

--

```
public class MyCompositeViewModel : IMyCompositeViewModel {

    public bool DetailisVisible{get;set;}

    public MyDetailViewModel DetailViewModel { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try binding by element name instead:

```
<UserControl 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    x:Class="Example.MyCompositeView"
    x:Name="root"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=MyCompositeViewModel}"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="300"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

     <Grid>
        <detail:MyDetailView 
            DataContext="{Binding Path=DetailViewModel}"
            Visibility="{Binding ElementName="root"},
                Path=DataContext.DetailsIsVisible,
                Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilty}}" />
     </Grid>

 </UserControl>
```

or flip the property order:

```
<UserControl 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    x:Class="Example.MyCompositeView"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=MyCompositeViewModel}"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="300"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

     <Grid>
        <detail:MyDetailView            
            Visibility="{Binding DetailsIsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilty}}" 
            DataContext="{Binding DetailViewModel}"/>
     </Grid>

 </UserControl>
```